# Calculating the sum of primes in Python - what purpose does this line of code serve?

Tags: python, calculator

I have a short function that will calculate the sum of all prime numbers up to a limit. Here is the full code for context:

```
def primes_sum(limit):
    limitn = limit+1
    not_prime = [False] * limitn
    primes = []

    for i in range(2, limitn):
        if not_prime[i]:
            continue
        for f in xrange(i*2, limitn, i):
            not_prime[f] = True

        primes.append(i)

    return sum(primes)
```

Most of this makes sense to me, but I don't understand this part:

```
not_prime = [False] * limitn
```

What exactly is the purpose of this? How does it work and how does it find out whether or not a number is prime? I've tried looking it up, but I can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply creating a `list` of length `limitn` with all it's element initialized to `False`.

`*` is a repetition operator. When applied on a `List` with an `integer` value `n` as the `right` operand, it repeats the `list` `n` times.

You can use it over strings also:

```
>>> [False] * 2
[False, False]
>>> "rohit" * 2
rohitrohit
```

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It initializes a list of `limitn` `False` values.  e.g.:

```
>>> [False]*3
[False, False, False]
```

Basically it prevents you from getting an `IndexError` later on.

Answer (score 0):

`[False]*n` initializes list with n elements which are all False. That way of initialization is often used as a way of optimization when you know how much elements will list contain in advance - it's *much* faster than adding elements with .append().